# Mostrar Imagen en un PictureBox usando Ozeki SDK y C#

Tags: c#

es posible mostrar en un PictureBox el video de la camara Web usando el SDK de Ozeki.

`Codigo`:

```
using Ozeki;
using Ozeki.Media;
using Ozeki.Camera;
namespace Cam
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _videoViewer = new VideoViewerWF();
            _imageProvider = new DrawingImageProvider();
            _mediaConnector = new MediaConnector();
        }
        private VideoViewerWF _videoViewer;
        private IWebCamera _webCamera;
        private DrawingImageProvider _imageProvider;
        private MediaConnector _mediaConnector;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _webCamera = new WebCamera();
            if (_webCamera != null)
            {
                _mediaConnector.Connect(_webCamera.VideoChannel, _imageProvider);                   
                _videoViewer.SetImageProvider(_imageProvider); //Original
                _videoViewer.SetImageProvider(pictureBox1); //Mostrar en el PictureBox
                _webCamera.Start();
                _videoViewer.Start();
            }
        }
        private void SetVideoViewer()
        {
         _videoViewer.Location = new Point(10, 10);
         _videoViewer.Size = new Size(250, 200);
         _videoViewer.BackColor = Color.Black;
         _videoViewer.TabStop = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox' to 'Ozeki.Media.IImageProvider'

[References, y codigo Fuente](http://www.camera-sdk.com/p_35-how-to-connect-to-an-usb-camera-and-display-the-picture-in-c-onvif.html)

Comment: Admito que desconozco este SDK, pero, viendo la [documentación](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/doc/html/e20bf95c-e7b6-f6fa-31e5-4f49221b1754.htm) se podría usar [Converter](http://www.voip-sip-sdk.com/doc/html/1d0f96f8-5821-3c49-1c0c-49e5abb602a8.htm) para convertir el arreglo de bytes a una imagen. ¿Cómo te devuelve la imagen capturada por la webcam, en un arreglo o algún valor que puedas usar?. El enlace que colocas también menciona que ese código funciona si la webcam soporta esa característica.